# Updating Content Specific Caching NGINX + Wordpress

Tags: nginx, vps, wordpress

somewhat new to setting up a web server. I am using a VPS from digital ocean with nginx installed to host a wordpress site. I am trying to play around with content specific caching rules and am basically just running a test. So far I've gone in and edited the nginx.conf file to modify headers for ALL responses and am now trying to do so for my website and particular types of content.  So in my sites-enabled folder, I have opened the file for my site and added the following:

```
server {
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  listen 80;

  root /home/myuser/www/www.mywebsite.com;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
  }

  location ~* \.(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|bmp|zip|woff2)$ {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      add_header Test Working;
  }

  location ~ /(.|wp-config.php|readme.html|licence.txt) {
      return 404;
  }

}
```

Neither set of directives in the location blocks are working. Again, this is somewhat new to me but I haven't found an answer as these are pretty basic modifications. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

As far as I can tell, I am trying to grab any resource that ends in the list (.woff, .css, etc...) and setting a header for those assets specifically...

Comment: *Neither set of directives in the location blocks are working* : can you be more specific about this ? What *"doesn't work"* ? What's the observed behaviour ? And and how do you test it ? See [how can I ask better questions on ServerFault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) to see what's the expected format.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. The Test Working header is not seen in any asset request via the network tab in chrome devtools (of the types specified). I was just trying to add a test header to ensure I'm doing it properly. Thanks.

Comment: You meant *reply* instead of *request*, right ? A quick guess is that these reply headers are actually cached  by your browser, thus you get them from a previous request. Try testing in a private navigation tab or using cli tools like `curl`/`wget`.